# Is there anything I can do to stop a Codex from cloning?

Tags: xcom-2

Every time I do damage to a Codex, it clones itself immediately. Is there any way to make fighting these things easier?

Comment: They don't clone if you kill them outright, so lining up a crit or a rapid shot can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Use flashbangs. Disorientation caused by flashbangs will prevent them from cloning, as answered before.
- Codex can also be stunned. Examples include Arc Blade attacks(note, however, that it has a fairly low chance of 25%).
- Codex registers as mechanical with respect to EMP grenades and Bluescreen rounds. If you have appropriately high tech level, then you could rather try suppressing that thing FOREVER. A shot from a Plasma Lance with a Bluescreen round will instantly kill it if the hit is delivered properly.

  - Codex can still clone itself when it is at HP 1, but this will result in the source being killed. This will degrade the cloning attempt into teleportation.
  - Although they COUNT as multiple attacks, damages from multi-attack abilities (Rapid Fire, Chain Shot, Fan Fire) are resolved at once. Therefore, if a Codex dies from such an ability, it does not reproduce, even though it had received multiple hits from the attacker.
- Certain Psi abilities are possible to hinder a Codex. Examples include Stasis, Insanity, or Void Rift. You can even try Dominating it. (Note, however, that a dominated Codex does NOT replicate.)

Comment: Stun also works, tried it with my ranger.

Comment: @zozo I almost forgot that... Note taken. Added it to the answer.

Comment: Just tried Void Rift on a codex. It took 4 damage, panicked, and then cloned itself! :( The best part is that the panicked codex then tried to attack another of my enemies.

Comment: I wonder if a Gas grenade affects them, any idea?

Answer (score 8):

I just learned this from some players chatting in a Twitch stream. You can actually disable a Codex's ability to clone itself by disorienting it with a Flashbang grenade first!

Comment: Just curious. If a Codex already has a clone out, and you flashbang the original, will the clone disappear or does it just prevent the Codex from cloning again?

Comment: @skully no idea, I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I confirmed that being disoriented prevents the codex from duplicating. It also prevents them from teleporting and most importantly from using that annoying mass weapon disable trick. That makes them very valuable targets for flashbangs.

Comment: @skully Did not try with flashbang, but from my encounters it seems like clones are totally autonomous. They will attack, use powers, teleport, and clone just as the original.

Answer (score 0):

Learn "Stasis" psionic ability. When you meet group of enemies with codex, put codex in stasis, the encounter will be much easier. Get rid of it later.