# Is it normal to spawn a pod of 3 Codex aliens?

Tags: xcom-2

Playing XCOM2 on <s>easy</s> veteran difficulty and just spawned a pod of triple Codexes.  I'm wondering if that's normal, or if my RNG is particularly helpful today.

[image: Triple Codex pod]

Comment: Related: [Is there anything I can do to stop a Codex from cloning?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255325/35432)

Comment: What month and year is it on the geoscape?

Comment: @RoijanEskor I think it was around October 2035.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

The longer you play the campaign, the stronger the groups of enemies you will face in random battles. Most enemies which you encounter in a story mission for the first time will then start to appear as a regular random encounter. This includes Codexes. You seem to already have a Ranger with the maximum rank and the best shotgun in the game, so you seem to be already playing for a while.

So if you start hitting your skill ceiling, you might want to focus on completing the story objectives and finish the game.

Comment: +1 for completing story objectives.  It's been a while since I played XCOM2, but I also seem to recall reading something about how codex aliens (in particular) will begin spawning more frequently if you go a while without completing their story quest - to make sure you aren't getting stonewalled by the game for not being able to find a codex.  **Looking at that screenshot, it seems the OP still hasn't finished that specific quest line.**

Comment: @Steve-O I also think that the game increases the spawn-weight of the Codexes while the player has that objective, but I did not find a reliable source for that anywhere, so I didn't want to spread a possibly false information.

Comment: @Steve-O Good observation. I think you're correct; after I completed that questline I didn't encounter Codexes anymore. Interestingly when launching that mission my Shadow Chamber forecast one Codex, that's why I was surprised when 3 showed up (unless I'm reading it wrong or it just predicts alien types, not counts).

Comment: @rkagerer The shadow chamber does only predict types, and the total count of aliens. It does not predict quantities of each type, as evidenced by the number of types not equaling the number of total aliens predicted.